# Why does my Adobe AIR app say the latest update is damaged?

Tags: air, adobe

I have written an HTML/AJAX application with Adobe Air and run it on my WinXP laptop. But now I've released a newer version on my update site, the application downloads the update and says "The application could not be installed because the AIR file is damaged. Try obtaining a new AIR file from the application author."

I've tried repackaging the application and incrementing the version number but that hasn't helped. I am creating it in Aptana Studio on OSX.

Can anyone explain please what could cause that error?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with aptana but...

in adobe flex builder, you have to change the first line of the file: "applicationName-app.xml". (where applicationName is the name of your application or project)

When you change from pc to mac-osx you have to change the line:

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/1.1">
```

to

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/1.5">
```

Don't know if you have this file when creating a project in aptana... maybe in the project properties.

Then repackage and deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem. After trying every "solution" mentioned on every blog on the planet it occurred to me that my server didn't have .air as a recognized MIME type. Once I added this, all was well.